# Vue.js: How to Use a Variable from Another Component in a Method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have some data in a Vue component (we'll call it Data.vue) like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            data1: {some data}
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to use that data on another page (Main.vue) in a method.

```
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        someMethod: function(){
            console.log(this.data1)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How would I go about doing this?

I did try importing it the data to "Main.vue" like this:

```
import { data1 } from '@/components/Data'
```

What other steps do I need to take?

Comment: you should take a look about mixins https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: like mentioned above `mixins` is one option (according to your situation) because global mixins is big NO NO. Another way is you can send the data1 as prop and watch it for changes... OR you can use VUEX.

Answer (score 2):

You may have more than one component `Data` and then it doesn't becomes clear which one you want to share.

If you have only one component then you can just export data

```
<script>
const data1 = {some data}

export { data1 }

export default {
    data () {
        return {
           data1
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and then your import should work.

```
import { data1 } from '@/components/Data'
```

But this is kindof hacky, you should use a store live [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Your Q is too general because It depends (From child to parent? global data? read-only data? and so on).

One basic way is by props. **Example:** Pass data (array/object/string and so on) From parent-to-child
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

**"Hello world example"**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('child', {
  // camelCase in JavaScript
  props: ['message_from_parent'],
  template: '<h3>{{ message_from_parent }}</h3>',
  created: function () {
    console.log(this.message_from_parent)
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child v-bind:message_from_parent="message"></child>
</div>
```

Or the opposite (From child to parent) by $emit:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on